# While loop vs a for loop in finding sum of multiples of 3 and 5 under 1000

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop

not really familiar with while loops but I thought it was an alternative so this may be an elementary mistake.

I need to look for the sum of natural numbers under 1000 that are multiples of 3 and 5. E.g for under 10

```
multiples of 3 and 5 < 10 = 3,5,6,9
sum = 23
```

My code using a for loop works and is as follows (this was my initial solution):

```
def multiple():
    lst = []
    for x in range(334): #didn't know how else to use a for loop but to find the largest value of x using a calculator
        if 3*x < limit:
            lst.append(3*x)
        if 5*x< 1000:
            lst.append(5*x)
        if (3*x > 1000) and (5*x > 1000): #unnecessary in a forloop with a range but this is just to maintain symmetry with while loop
            break 
    lst2 = list(set(lst)) #remove duplicates 
    print(sum(lst2))

multiple()
```

My code using a while loop(this solution doesn't even come out in te console --> maybe this is were the error lies):

```
def multiple():
    lst = []
    while True:
        x = 1
        if 3*x < 1000:
            lst.append(3*x)
        if 5*x< 1000:
            lst.append(5*x)
        if (3*x > 1000) and (5*x > 1000):
            break
        x += 1
    lst2 = list(set(lst)) #remove duplicates 
    print(sum(lst2))

multiple()
```

Desired output:

```
233168
```

In addition to how to rectify the while loop, any improvements on my for loop or while loop would also be welcome. Thanks

Comment: So it is multiples of 3 *or* 5?

Comment: Multiples of 3 and 5 if that wasn't clear @KlausD.

Comment: Try printing the value of `x` after the loop, and work from there. (Also, I think looping to 1000 and picking values where `x % 3` or `x % 5` is zero would be better.)

Comment: Then the lowest number would be 15.

Comment: I think theres a misunderstanding, the example I shown was for under 10. But I am looking for sum of multiples of 3 and multiples of 5 under 1000, not common multiples. Sorry I think that's where the misunderstanding is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Critically Debugging**

Since you're new, let's take this opportunity to analyze the bug before we solve it. Note first that you did not notice any printouts at all. Therefore, your `print()` statement was either not running, or was printing only spaces. We can rule out the latter since sum() will return an integer.

Therefore, the `print()` is never run. The function is defined and called correctly, so that's not the issue. Now notice `while True:`; this is an early warning sign. If the while loop never ends, the `print()` will never run. We do notice there are multiple `break` statements that should stop the loop, but it's likely there's an issue with them.

Now we check how the loop updates. First, note the `i+=1`. That seems right. However, `i=1` is also within the while loop. This cannot be correct, since every iteration `i` will be reset. This would cause the loop to run forever.

This type of critical analysis of code is only built through practice, but hopefully this answer offers some insight into how you could have fixed this issue yourself (and how I looked through your code).

Also note that adding print statements into the while loop to test would have allowed you to notice that `i` was always 1.

**Working Code**

```
def multiple():
    lst = []
    x = 1 # moved from line below
    while True:
        # x = 1 should not go here
        if 3*x < 1000:
            lst.append(3*x)
        if 5*x< 1000:
            lst.append(5*x)
        if (3*x > 1000) and (5*x > 1000):
            break
        x += 1
    lst2 = list(set(lst)) #remove duplicates 
    print(sum(lst2))

multiple()
```

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you, I will try to reason out this way next time when I debug. Also will try this code to see if it works thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A fairly straight forward approach is to iterate over every number from 1 to 1000 and check if it is divisible by 3 or 5, and then sum them all up.

```
total = sum(x for x in range(1, 1001) if x%3 == 0 or x%5 == 0)
total
# returns:
234168
```

Comment: To iterate from 1 to 1000 how can we do that without using range as range includes 0, just asking

Comment: If 2 arguments are passed to the `range` function, it will create a `range` object with the start and stop as the two arguments.  In other words, `range(1,10)` iterates from 1 to 9; `range(7, 30)` iterates from 7 to 29, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Always thought that 2 arguements are ending and step, should read the documentation properly.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

**Using for loop:**

```
def multiple():
    sum = 0
    for _ in xrange(1, 1001):
        if _ % 3 == 0 or _ % 5 == 0:
            sum += _

    return sum

print(multiple())
```

**Using while loop:**

```
def multiple():
    sum = 0
    cnt = 1
    while cnt <= 1000:
        if cnt % 3 == 0 or cnt % 5 == 0:
            sum += cnt
        cnt += 1
    return sum

print(multiple())
```

**output:**

```
234168
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative! This is so much more efficient than mine!

Comment: @KOOTSHOOTS glad to know :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def multiple():
    lst = []
    x=1
    while (3*x < 1000) or (5*x < 1000):
        if 3*x < 1000:
            lst.append(3*x)
        if 5*x < 1000:
            lst.append(5*x)
        x += 1
    lst2 = list(set(lst)) #remove duplicates
    print(sum(lst2))

multiple()
```